# md5 different after decompressing the file and compressing it again

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar

Host: Ubuntu 14.04

Command md5sum

File size: Before/After decompressing: 77.8 M - 323.9

I downloaded the file from Ubuntu official website.
[Where I download it from](http://system-image.ubuntu.com/pool/device-e44a795767ceec9680a9760f30ec572a0ebb85445f21254b3b47e78ae9b8cee3.tar.xz) ( device.tar.xz )

Before decompressing the file, I use md5sum to generate the md5 number for this compressed file.

After this, I decompressed the file, however, I dont modify any content inside. And then I re-compressed the file ( device2.tar.xz ).

By comparing two md5 number, it is different. I doubt my decompression may cause something changed.

Is there anyway to ensure that the content will be exactly the same after re-compressing ?

Thanks

Comment: Compression tools have flexible choice of algorithm and compression level. The guarantee is that (compress -> decompress) will be invariant; there is no guarantee that (decompress -> compress) will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hashing two different compressed representations of the same uncompressed data.

The `xz` file format includes some meta-data, which you can see with `xz -l foo.xz`.  So even if you used the same version of the same compression program with the same settings, you could get output files that weren't byte-for-byte identical.